# Convert ViewController Code for RTSP to Swift File to Call into View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

I am trying to write an app that takes in RTSP Video and I would like to ultimately use the AVCaptureSession functionality to record and save video.

I have been able to stream live video through my View Controller using this code.  When I try move the code to another swift file I get error regarding the combination of Objective C that the View Controller lets you call but the function I am trying to write will now allow it. This is the update function.  Also I don't quite understand this part of the code as it seems to reference the ViewController, and I am not sure what It needs to reference instead if placed outside the ViewController **"target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update),**

The ViewController Code is currently utilizing an interface created in C file that looks like this to create the RTSP player.

Also if anyone can help me with how to get a UIImage as the device type used for a AVCaptureSession/PreviewLayer It would be very helpful.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView! var video: RTSPPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        video = RTSPPlayer(video: "rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.150.243", usesTcp: false)
        video.outputWidth = Int32(UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        video.outputHeight = Int32(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        video.seekTime(0.0)

        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0/30, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.update), userInfo: nil,
repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }

    @objc func update(timer: Timer) {
        if(!video.stepFrame()){
            timer.invalidate()
            video.closeAudio()
        }
        imageView.image = video.currentImage
    }

}
```